# Cell with #REF! error causes COM Exception when used to get a multi-cell range

Tags: c#, excel, com

I have a row of data, and a row of cells below it that all have #REF! errors.  I want to drag the data row down over the error row, using the following:

```
Excel.Range topLeft=ReportSheet.Cells[1,1];
Excel.Range topRight=ReportSheet.Cells[1,10];
Excel.Range bottomRight=ReportSheet.Cells[3,10];
Excel.Range sourceRange = ReportSheet.Cells[topLeft, topRight];
Excel.Range targetRange = ReportSheet.Cells[topLeft, bottomRight];
sourceRange.AutoFill(targetRange);
```

The `sourceRange` is assigned with no problem, but assigning `targetRange` (which includes the row with the #REF! errors) throws a COM Exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

Any ideas on how I can avoid this exception?

UPDATE: I tried deleting the #REF! rows before attempting to execute the AutoFill.  Same error.  `sourceRange.AutoFill` works fine on test data where there are no error rows below the data.

Comment: Excel error 1004 is a pretty crappy error that has many causes.  Not actually that likely to be caused by cells with bad references.  Google the phrase to learn more about it.

Comment: @HansPassant, I'm getting this error because I deleted the row on another sheet that these cells reference (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866139/prevent-excel-from-deleting-reference-in-formula-when-row-is-deleted)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this.  There were two issues:

- Setting the `targetRange` requires using `ReportSheet.Range` instead of `ReportSheet.Cells`
- `AutoFill` only works 1-dimensionally, i.e. a row filling other rows or column filling other columns.  My original code was failing, I think, because setting `targetRange` as `Range[topLeft,bottomRight]` meant that `AutoFill` had to fill down and right.

The revised, working code is:

```
Excel.Range topLeft=ReportSheet.Cells[1,1];
Excel.Range bottomLeft=ReportSheet.Cells[3,1];
Excel.Range topRight=ReportSheet.Cells[1,10];
Excel.Range bottomRight=ReportSheet.Cells[3,10];
Excel.Range topRow=ReportSheet.Range[topLeft,topRight];
Excel.Range bottomRow=ReportSheet.Range[bottomLeft,bottomRight];
Excel.Range targetRange=ReportSheet.Range[topRow,bottomRow];
topRow.AutoFill(targetRange);
```

I got a clue from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1528853/619177).

Answer (score 0):

```
Excel.Range temp1 =ReportSheet.Cells[1,1];
Excel.Range temp2 =ReportSheet.Cells[1,2];
Excel.Range temp3 =ReportSheet.Cells[1,20];
Excel.Range sourceRange = ReportSheet.Cells[temp1 , temp2 ];
Excel.Range targetRange = ReportSheet.Cells[temp1 , temp3];
sourceRange.AutoFill(targetRange);
```

Try above it will work.

**Destination of Auto Fill must include the source range.**

Comment: That's pretty much exactly the code that I presented above, which throws the exception.  My `Autofill` destination includes the source range, which was `topLeft`. The only difference, as far as I can tell, is that yours doesn't go down past the first row.  Am I missing something?